# I can't use acute accents (Latex interpreter form) on Matlab

Tags: accents, matlab

I intend to use an acute accent on a letter, for example, "é", inside a legend of a *Matlab* graph which uses a LaTeX Interpreter form.

In Latex code we can write "é" using `\'{e}`. On Matlab the corresponding code would be `\'e`. The problem is that apostrophe symbol is currently used for strings declaration on *Matlab* code. And so, `\'e` will not work.

But I can't find any alternative in `\'e` in the literature. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe  try `{\'e}`?

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work...

Comment: Please try to use `\''` (two single quotes after the backslash). I found this [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/101095?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Comment: You're right, it now works. Thank you. You can write your answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Matlab you can use the following sequence to typeset the following character with an acute: `\''`.